# Is it possible to work with AST inside D code?

Tags: d, abstract-syntax-tree, anonymous-function

I'm not talking about dynamic programming. My wish is to work in compile time with constructions like:

```
obj.where(x => x.some_val >= 14); // <-- LINQ-style :D
```

To have a possibility to work directly with AST of single-expression function-argument:

```
(>=)
  |--(14)
  +--(.)
      |--(x)
      +--(some_val)
```

Now I've got only the idea to use some special class for x-objects with all operators (like `+`/`-`/`*`/`.`/...) strongly overridden in some crazy dirty way to collect the information about anonymous function AST structure (if and only if this class is the only class to use in this single-expression function).

Like tiny AST for single r-value.

Is it technically possible somehow?

Comment: Isn't what you ask for simply a filter using lambda??

Comment: Do you insist on a D-based solution to manipulating ASTs for D code, or are you interested in a solution that could work with D source code, but isn't implmeneted in D?

Comment: @DejanLekic Filtering with lambda is a pretty basic tool from the standard library (no, it was not what I was looking for). 
It's a pity, you make such assumptions, that means my question seems to be not really smart :)

Comment: Dejan, what I think he wants is something like .NET's expression tree or Nim nodes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx http://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html Unfortunately that's not possible in D. It's a little sad considering D's amazing compile-time as AST's would make it perfect and so much easier to do code generation. Sadly it'll probably never come. You could do a hacky way of it though by creating a parser that does it for you then create a module that contains your tree, but it's a long way around and isn't really flexible.

Comment: @TimushevRoman - my intention was not to insult your intelligence (I apologise if you got such an impression), but simply to note that what you are asking can indeed be done by a lambda.  If you need something that can't be done with a lambda, then by all means give us an example that demonstrates AST modification requirement.

Comment: @Bauss - there are people (including me) in the D community that think AST manipulation and macros are a highway to hell... AST manipulation is abused in all languages that supports it. About macros... I will not even think about it - it just reminds me of the pain I had with C++ and pains I still have with C... Walter is IMHO right about being firmly against them.

Comment: @DejanLekic My initial goal was to investigate the possibility of compile time SQL-commands construction. Lambdas look like being useful to define "WHERE"-statements. To use lambdas this way one should somehow obtain their semantic meaning to transform it to SQL syntax. This is not some serious task - just an object of my curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate code at compile time, then you can use strings with string mixins. e.g.

```
string foo(string name, int value)
{
    return format("auto %s = %s;", name, value);
}

void bar()
{
    mixin(foo("i", 42));
    assert(i == 42);
}
```

That's not a particular interesting example, but as long as you can manipulate strings into the code you want, then you can mix them in, which allows for all kinds of code generation possibilities (both useful and abusive).

However, there is no way to actually manipulate the AST in D. As mentioned in Richard's answer as well as the comments, Walter is strongly against adding such capabilities to the language. So, it's highly unlikely that D will ever have them. But given how much you can do with string mixins, a lot of what someone might want to do with AST macros can be done with string mixins. They allow you to generate pretty much any code that you might want to. They just don't allow you to manipulate existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, and Walter has been fairly against it in the past e.g. AST macros.